# How to add a non-breaking space to a rich text field?

Tags: redactor, richtext

Seems like a basic question but I can’t figure out a way to do this out of the box, or reference to it in the Redactor docs. `‘&nbsp;’` always gets stripped out.

Comment: The one-click button seems like a reasonable option. Otherwise, resolving why something gets stripped when it shouldn’t is still an issue. When i’m putting content in markup, I use this same method but we cannot expect the casual content editor to make sure the html it inserts is done properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using CSS `white-space: nowrap;` instead of `&nbsp;` characters? I guess that's semantically more correct and this also allows you to prevent your text to break at any other character (great for phone numbers etc.).

CSS:

```
.nobr {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Markup:

```
<p>my phone number is <span class="nobr">+1 800-275-8777</span></p>
```

To add this easily to your Redactor fields markup, have a look at the [inline format](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/inline/) API or the [formattingAdd](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#setting-formattingAdd) config setting (I actually had mixed experiences with that setting).

If you'd like to be able to add this with the click of a button, I also just added this to my [Redactor Inline Styles](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-redactorinlinestyles) plugin, which is a collection of (optional) buttons to apply inline styles to your Redactor texts (Quotes, Code, etc.).