# Display rich text redactor menubar with superscript/subscript buttons

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorclips

So my client want to have superscript and subscript buttons in the redactor toolbar like this :
https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/buttons-sup-and-sub/

[image]

I saw this [Stack Exchange post here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/how-can-i-use-small-sub-sub-within-a-redactor-rich-text-field) but it is just talking about the shortcuts and the way of making a plugin.

I tried adding the plugin directly in Craft Redactor config file `plugins: ['fullscreen','video','table','scriptbuttons'],` but of course did not work so easily.

Got Craft 2.4.2699. Is it possible ?
Is it on the Craft roadmap ?
Or should I make a feature request ?

Answer (score 1):

The definitive and most simple answer for all **Redactor Inline Styles** requests is this great plugin by **carlcs**:
https://github.com/carlcs/craft-redactorinlinestyles

Just perfect!
[image]

(found it thanks to this post [How to add a non-breaking space to a rich text field?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9812/how-to-add-a-non-breaking-space-to-a-rich-text-field))